# Sendgrid multiple attachments in c# not received in correct sequence

Tags: c#, email, attachment, sendgrid

I am using SendGrid to send mails in my program.
I am sending multiple files as attachments in the message. 
The attachment list gets attached in the correct sequence but when I receive them at my mail the sequence is broken.
I am using the following code for sending message :

```
public async void SendAsync(SendGridMessage message)       
{           
 var userName = "userName";
 var pwd = "Password";          
 var credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, pwd);          
 var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);
 try         
    {
        if (ColAttachedFiles != null)        
        {      
            var lstAttachmentsPath = (from objAttachmentDoc in ColAttachedFiles select objAttachmentDoc.FilePath).ToArray();  
            message.Attachments = lstAttachmentsPath;
        }         
        await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(message);                              
    }
    catch (Exception e)    
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message); 
    }
}
```

Here I have a list which contains multiple files which are then send as attachments in the message.
The list contains attachments in correct sequence (Ex: a.jpg, b.jpg, c.jpg, d.jpg, e.jpg) but when they are received at the recipient's mail, this sequence is broken.

Comment: It's quite tricky to control the sequence on the recipient's side. Maybe you should try a 1 second pause after sending each attachment? It's a dirty fix I know, but it might help.

Comment: I don't think that you can ever guarantee the order of receipt, because that task isn't handled by your sending code, but rather the mail server. If you don't artificially delay your sending loop (and that also doesn't guarantee the order will be preserved), I do not believe there's a good way to fulfill your request.